# Prevent BoolTool from arbitrary vertex additions on differences?

Tags: boolean-modifier

I find with anything involving more than a few objects, BoolTool will often create something that has non-manifold edges and other problems in ways that I'm sure are deterministic but that I cannot predict. Apart from using FAR more detail that is necessary for spheres, cylinders, etc., none of it is really that complicated. Making a simple box with cylindrical holes in it, for example, will result in some faces having

The model below was just a repeated application of unions and differences of cylinders and cubes. It requires a ton of cleanup.

[image]

It's difficult to reproduce, but I found that, for example, when it creates an edge on a face I'm making a hole in, it will sometimes add a vertex at a place that doesn't intersect with an edge that's being cut out.

[image]

On the bottom is a vertex that makes sense to me. There was an edge of the shape of the cut intersecting the face I'm cutting out of. On the top, however, it added a vertex *between* two such vertices. This resulted in a non-flat face. Both of those vertices are just running an edge out to the corner of a cube.

I would accept as an answer "don't use BoolTool; use something else and here's why you won't have this problem with that something else." That being said, the boolean modifier seems to have done the same exact thing.

Comment: it would help if you had a reproducable example which we could check out - so uploading a blend file would help (with a non applied boolean modifier)

Comment: @Becca You seem to be doing a lot of hard surface work, for which an actual CAD application would be a lot more suited. Have you looked into FreeCAD?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, I have not. I will look into it. Thank you!